# Jumbling data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've dataset which look like this(Raw Data) :-

[image]

And I want to jumble or sort the data like Book 1 - Topic A and next row Book 2 - Topic B, so one book-chapter and next book and chapter, if we does that, data should look like this :-

[image]

I somehow made it, but it's not getting data which has more chapter, like Book 3 has 3 Chapter and Book 4 has 4 chapter, so it's not extracting that.

Using this code now:-

```
function jumbling() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    const ssname = ss.getSheetByName('Raw')
    const data = ssname.getRange(2,1,ssname.getLastRow()-1,8).getValues()
    const lessons = [...new Set(data.map(function(r){return r.slice(3,4)}).flat())]
    const arr = []
    let j = 0
    console.log(lessons)
    let thisLesson
    let to_Len = 0
    
    for(let i = 0 ; i < lessons.length ; i++)
    {
       let k = 0
       while(k < lessons.length)
       {
        let thisLesson = data.filter(r=> r[3] === lessons[k])  
        arr.push(thisLesson[j])
        k += 1
       }
       j += 1
    }
  
    console.log(arr)
    ss.getSheetByName('Processed').getRange(1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr)
}
```

Comment: Where should be the extra elements? In your case Chapter 3 and 4 that don't have anothers to pair? At the bottom? So you should have your current result plus Chapter 3 and 4 at the bottom of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this formula, if it fits with your intention:

```
=SORT(A2:H,BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",COUNTIF(A2:each,each)))),1)
```

With BYROW it makes a cumulative count of each time an ID appears (I used A column to configure it, because I guessed that's the value of uniqueness, but can change it to column D if needed).

[image]